# Codename One - isAlwaysTensile(), setAlwaysTensile(), getTensileLength(), etc

Tags: codenameone

In the Codename One API, there are several methods that cointain the word "Tensile", such as isAlwaysTensile(), setAlwaysTensile(), getTensileLength(), etc.

I didn't find an explanation of the meaning of "Tensile" in the context of a mobile app. What are example of use of these methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tensile is the rubber band effect you get when you drag the UI beyond the edge and it lets you. Then you release and the UI bounces back into the valid position.

This is the common behavior in iOS, on Android a highlight color effect is used to indicate the same behavior.

Generally these methods are best lest alone, they are set by the platform themes and modifying them can result in unexpected behavior.